# Macro to match string value from sheet1, if matches copy the next cell value to sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find the match for each cell(C:C)value of sheet1  in sheet2 (C:C) and if the value matches copy the corresponding next cell i.e, D:D and replace in sheet 2. If it does not match then copy and paste the Range A to D in the next empty cell in sheet 2

```
    Sub Method1()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim bFailed As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    strSearch = Sheet1.Range("C2")
    i = 1
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down 1 row
    i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
    Loop
    'ActiveCell.Value = i

    On Error Resume Next
    strOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strSearch, Sheet2.Range("C:C"), 2, False) 
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then bFailed = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not bFailed Then
    MsgBox "corresponding value is " & vbNewLine & strOut
    Else
    MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
    End If
    End Sub
```

Sheet1:`enter code here
[image]

Sheet2:
[image]

Comment: What's your specific problem though?  What exactly is stopping you from achieving this?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am new to vba and do not have much knowledge. I would require the compete code on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not how it works here.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that, Tim
This what I have, now I need to reiterate for all the values in C:C, adding the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Method1()

    Dim cSearch As Range, m

    Set cSearch = Sheet1.Range("C2")

    Do While Len(cSearch.Value) > 0
        'omit the "WorksheetFunction" or this will throw a run-time error
        '   if there's no match. Instead we check the return value for an error
        m = Application.Match(cSearch.Value, Sheet2.Range("C:C"), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a match - update ColD on sheet2
            Sheet2.Cells(m, "D").Value = cSearch.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Else
            'no match - add row to sheet2 (edit)
            cSearch.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 4).Copy _
                     Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If

        Set cSearch = cSearch.Offset(1, 0) 'next value to look up
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for code, but unfortunately it does not function. Although it runs without errors but do not serve the purpose

Comment: Sorry Tim, but I do not see any changes.

Comment: Perfect, you were a great help. the code worked as it should. And with some modification I got what I wanted. (Y)

Comment: by any chance , can I count the number of replacement and new entries ?

Comment: Yes - just use a couple of variables and increment them inside the `If Then` block

Answer (score 0):

However,  I made change to my code and it does the job, but I want to repeat the function for each cell in C:C, have a look

```
                        Sub Method1()
                            Dim strSearch As String
                            Dim strOut As String
                            Dim bFailed As Boolean
                            Dim i As Integer

                            strSearch = Sheet1.Range("C2")
                            i = 1
                            'Do Until ActiveCell.Value = Empty
                                     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move down 1 row
                                     i = i + 1 'keep a count of the ID for later use
                                ' Loop

                             'ActiveCell.Value = i

                            On Error Resume Next
                            strOut = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(strSearch, Sheet2.Range("C:C"), 1, False)
                            If Err.Number <> 0 Then bFailed = True
                            On Error GoTo 0

                            If Not bFailed Then
                            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("e2").Copy
                            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("e2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                            MsgBox "corresponding value been copied " & vbNewLine & strOut
                            Else

                            MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
                            End If
                            End Sub
```